# How to select the first div tag in the nested div tags

Tags: jsoup

How to select first div tag.If i use div>* it selects all the div and i just want the tags inside the first div. Please Assist.

```
String htmlString = 
"<html><div><div><div><p><b>This is first line</b></p>   </div><b>This is second line</b></div><div><span style=\"color:blue\">This is third line</span></div></html>"`;

            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

            Elements elements1 = doc1.select("html:first-child");

            for (Element element : elements1) {
                System.out.println(element.toString());
            }
```

i want the output as,

```
<div>
    <div>
     <p><b>This is first line</b></p>
    </div>
    <b>This is second line</b>    </div>    <div>
    <span style="color:blue">This is third line</span>    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html() to get the inside of a div

```
String result = doc1.select("div").first().html();
System.out.println(result);
```